# Stripe gateway with nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I used Stripe payment gateway to add a payment option in my project, in my user schema model I have added an isPaid(which is a boolean var and false by default), on successful payment, I want to make isPaid = true,  following is my index.js and checkout.js, but on trying to implement req.user.isPaid=true; I either cant access this variable or it becomes true before the payment.Looking forward to some help

```
// // GET checkout
    
router.get('/checkout', middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.isPaid) {
        req.flash('success', 'Your account is already paid');
        return res.redirect('/students');
    }
    // payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
    res.render('checkout', { amount: 100 });
});

const calculateOrderAmount = items => {
  
  return 100;
};
router.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  try{
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "inr"
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
  });
    }
    catch(e){

    }
});
```

This is my checkout.js

//checkout.js

```
    var stripe = Stripe(process.env.SecretKey);
    
    // The items the customer wants to buy
    var purchase = {
        items: [{ id: "Teacher Registration Fee" }],
        currency: "inr"
        };
    
    // Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
    fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
    })
      .then(function(result) {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        var elements = stripe.elements();
        var style = {
          base: {
            color: "#32325d",
            fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
            fontSize: "16px",
            "::placeholder": {
              color: "#32325d"
            }
          },
          invalid: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
            color: "#fa755a",
            iconColor: "#fa755a"
          }
        };
        var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
        // Stripe injects an iframe into the DOM
        card.mount("#card-element");
        card.on("change", function (event) {
          // Disable the Pay button if there are no card details in the Element
          document.querySelector("button").disabled = event.empty;
          document.querySelector("#card-error").textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
        });
        var form = document.getElementById("payment-form");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
          payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
        });
      });
    // Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
    // If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
    // prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
    var payWithCard = function(stripe, card, clientSecret) {
      loading(true);
      stripe
        .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
          payment_method: {
            card: card
          }
        })
        .then(function(result) {
          if (result.error) {
            // Show error to your customer
            showError(result.error.message);
          } else {
            // The payment succeeded!
            orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
          }
        });
    };
    /* ------- UI helpers ------- */
    // Shows a success message when the payment is complete
    var orderComplete = function(paymentIntentId) {
      loading(false);
      document
        .querySelector(".result-message a")
        .setAttribute(
          "href",
          "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments/" + paymentIntentId
        );
      document.querySelector(".result-message").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
    };
    // Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
    var showError = function(errorMsgText) {
      loading(false);
      var errorMsg = document.querySelector("#card-error");
      errorMsg.textContent = errorMsgText;
      setTimeout(function() {
        errorMsg.textContent = "";
      }, 4000);
    };
    // Show a spinner on payment submission
    var loading = function(isLoading) {
      if (isLoading) {
        // Disable the button and show a spinner
        document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
      } else {
        document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
      }
    };
```

Comment: Hi Yawar, Express doesn't have a `user` property on the request object as far as I know. From what I gather, you'd likely want to look into setting up some form of role based access control. The idea is that you would create an internal representation of a user (i.e., a User model) in your database, which you would then update if the paid or not. I would recommend Googling "Role Based Access Control + Node/Express" for inspiration on an approach that suits your needs!

Comment: hey ttmarek! Your perception is completely valid, but I have already lead it that way by creating the UserModel, and the problem here is to update the value of the properties of the User schema that is isPaid.

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: String,
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    isPaid: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);